# Text to Speech without button(will be continuous act)

Tags: java, android

this project code belongs to the project for the blinds to purchase the items. the scanresult fetch the details to the textview and reads for them and uses gesture options to handle the app.
i created the android project byr barcode scanner and output as textview and voice output. used xzing library as you can see it in the code. the problem is after showing the scanresult in plaintext, it does't atuostart the audio output functionallity. that is the real usage of this project. i referred youtube but can't. then making a chance to anyone to fix this program to text to voice.
this is my code, when working no errors at all. but no audio output after the scanresult from the barcodescanner. i tried my level best. so anyone can help out of it ??/?.

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA =1;
private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
TextView result;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(scannerView);
    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Firebase connection is successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if(checkPermission())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "permission is granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}
private boolean checkPermission()
{
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SecondActivity.this, CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
}
private void requestPermission()
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permission[], int grantResults[])
{
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length > 0)
            {
                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if(cameraAccepted)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    {
                        if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CAMERA))
                        {
                            displayAlertMessage("you need to allow access for both permission",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            requestPermissions(new String[]{CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                                        }
                                    });
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        if(checkPermission())
        {
            if(scannerView == null)
            {
                scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
                setContentView(scannerView);
            }
            scannerView.setResultHandler(this);
            scannerView.startCamera();
        }
        else
        {
            requestPermission();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    scannerView.stopCamera();
}
public void displayAlertMessage(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(SecondActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", listener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();

}
EditText ed1;
TextToSpeech txt;
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String scanResult = result.getText();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   /* long n=890103073;
    long n1=Integer.parseInt(scanResult);
    if(n1 == n)
        text.setText("Pears Bathing Bar, Pure and Gentle.98% pure Glycerin & Natural Oils. Net weight 75 grams. MRP rupees 105 ");

    */
    text.setText(scanResult);
    scannerView.stopCamera();

     txt=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR)
            {
                txt.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });
    String  toSpeak=ed1.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    txt.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);

    /* public void onPause()
    {
        if(txt!=null)
        {
            txt.stop();
            txt.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }*/

    /*AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            scannerView.resumeCameraPreview(SecondActivity.this);
        }
    });
    builder.setNeutralButton("Visit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(scanResult));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.setMessage(scanResult);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();*/
}
```

}

Comment: This takes time: `txt=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()` so if you call `txt.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);` right after it, it won't work. You need to init the TTS engine at application startup, keep the instance and then call `speak()` using it whenever there's something to speak. Or at least you'll need to wait for `onInit()` to run, but that would introduce a noticeable delay in your app.

Comment: thank you sir. would you please suggest another way to implement this...

Comment: will you please help me to suggest how to add the facility of double tap and gesture options in my app